# Will QString::fromLocal8Bit() use UTF-8 when needed?

Tags: qt, internationalization, locale, qstring

UTF-8 is an 8-bit encoding. User can have LANG set to for example ja_JP.utf8, so this makes this then also a "local", Japanese encoding. All things seem to match, but documentation only states that QTextCodec::codecForLocale() will be used, and its documentation doesn't say if it's only about Latin1 vs Latin2 vs etc. (although "codec for locale" sounds like arbitrary codec for the LANG setting would be used, even non-8bit one, is also this true?).

Comment: `ja_JP` is the locale, `utf8` the encoding?

Comment: @peppe: well codecForLocale() sounds like if also your locale was considered encoding or at least something that influences encoding. But in general you're probably right